# WCF e Horario de Verão

Tags: c#, iis, wcf

Estou com um problema de conversão de datas no WCF.

Recebo um Json um DateTime no formato Unix

```
 "\/Date(1477320927000)\/" - 24-10-2016 12:55:27.
```

O Wcf recebe esta data como `24-10-2016 14:55:27.` Esta dando uma diferença de 2 horas.

Tentei usar `TimeZone`, `CultureInfo`, `DateTimeKind`, `DateTimeOffSet`, etc.. Mas nada funcionou ou coloca uma 1 a menos ou 2 horas a mais.

Alguém sabe como resolver isto?

Comment: Poste o código que você está usando..

Comment: Na Verdade o que acontece é que a data sai certa e chega errada no WCF. Basicamente o que fiz foi: dataRecebida.ToLocalTime(); DateTime.SpecifyKind(dataRecebida, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)..

Comment: É que '1477320927000' equivale à' 24 Oct 2016 14:55:27', pode testar [aqui](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm), para testar remova os últimos 3 dígitos ex: '1477320927',

Comment: Acredito que este conversor não esteja validando o TimeZone, olha este [link](http://www.epochconverter.com). Neste é exibido das duas formas.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o seguinte método:

```
public static DateTime FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Int64 value)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime((value * 10000) + 621355968000000000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return dt.ToLocalTime();
}
```

Imagem da saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]